# Accessing a SQL db from an Apache/Mono server

Tags: .net, sql, apache, mono

I have an Apache Server running Mono for a .net site (it's a mess). The SQL database is hosted on web.com, on a virtual IIS server.

My connection string works when the site and the DB aren't separated, but when they are there's nothing there.

Here's what I've got in the web.config:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ConnectionString"     value="server=mssql2.myregisteredsite.com;uid=******;Integrated Security=SSPI;pwd=****;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;database=*****;pooling=true;max pool size=1000" />
</appSettings>
```

and for some reason, it's in two places

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SiteDB" connectionString="data source=mssql2.myregisteredsite.com;Persist Security Info=True; initial catalog=****;user id=***** ; Network Library=DBMSSOCN;password=*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I've tried swapping out the source domain with an ip that's xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433 but that's not worked.